# Address IP to domains

Tags: ip

Is it possible to address IP to domain?
It gives me a security error

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^23.254.227.195$
RewriteRule (.*) http://noleggiovideoproiettoriroma.it/$1 [R=301,L]

That writing IP gives you the site and not a private page

I can send the whole .htaccess file